# c# case insensitive match in a LIST

Tags: c#

I have a list which is as follows.

```
List<string> Animallist = new List<string>();
Animallist.Add("cat");
Animallist.Add("dog");
Animallist.Add("lion and the mouse");
Animallist.Add("created the tiger");
```

I have a textbox where I enter

"Do not blame God for having created the TIGER, but thank him for not having given it wings”"

I would like to see which word(s) from the textbox matches items in the list and print the list on the console. The search has to be case insensitive. i.e TIGER in the text box should match tiger in the list.

in the above example "created the tiger" will be printed on the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var animalFound = Animals
    .Where(a=> a.Equals(searchAnimal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

- [String.Equals Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx)
- [Best practise: Choosing a StringComparison Member for Your Method Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx#choosing_a_stringcomparison_member_for_your_method_call)

or, if you also want to search the words:

```
var animalsFound = from a in Animals
             from word in a.Split()
             where word.Equals(searchAnimal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             select a;
```

oh, now i've seen your long text

```
string longText = "Do not blame God for having created the TIGER, but thank him for not having given it wings";
string[] words =  longText.Split();
var animalsFound = from a in Animals
             from word in a.Split()
             where words.Contains(word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             select a;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = "Do not blame God for having created the TIGER, but thank him for not having given it wings";
var matched = Animallist.Where(o => text.Contains(o, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
foreach (var animal in matched)
    Console.WriteLine(animal);
```

Specifying `StringComparer` or `StringComparison` will allow you to search for values that are case insensitive. Most `String` class methods will provide an overload that supports one of them.